# BFG remove multiple folders

Tags: git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

I found that BFG is much faster than the original git-filter-branch.

We have multiple svn repo to move to even more git repositories, this implies some repository folder merges and splits.
During the process I need to remove a set of root folders and I'd like to remove those to the whole history.

I tried to use the BFG **--delete-folders** and it works fine for one single folder but I did not find a way to delete multiple folders. Is it even possible ? or shall I loop to call BFG as many times as I have folders to remove ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

The argument to `--delete-folders` is a [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) expression, so you should be able to just comma-separate the folder names, like this:

```
$ bfg --delete-folders "{folderA,folderB,folderC}" my-repo.git
```

Good luck!

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).*

Comment: BFG is great! Is it possible to remove one instance of a folder with a given name in a repo if there are multiples? E.g. Given /config vs /some/other/path/config, removing the former from history without the latter?

Comment: Sorry I didn't want to sign up for Bountysource, so I'm giving you 5 karmas instead of $5. Amazingly easy to use.

Comment: Are the folder names relative, absolute, wildcards, or some kind of other matching system?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete multiple folder using the command like this:

```
$ bfg --delete-folders "{List of folder separated by comma}" git-repo.git
```

Thanks !